# understanding angularjs directives and data-binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

still working my head around angularjs directives and am a bit confused why this isn't working.

namely, i want a directive that tracks its position relative to a target and sets a target hit boolean. i also want to reuse this directive on my page, with each directive tracking a unique target.

```
app.directive('trackPosition', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            target: "=target"
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var navtop = elem[0].offsetTop; 
            window.onscroll = function() {
                var elemTop = elem[0].offsetTop;
                    targetTop = document.getElementById(scope.target).getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    console.log(scope.title + ", " + elemTop + ", " + targetTop);

                (targetTop <= elemTop && (-1 * targetTop) <= elemTop) ? scope.trackedTargetHit = true : scope.trackedTargetHit = false;
                scope.$apply();
            }
        }
    }
}]);


portfolio.controller('CtrlOne', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'CtrlOne';
    $scope.target = 'TargetOne';
    $scope.trackedTargetHit = false;
});

portfolio.controller('CtrlTwo', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'CtrlTwo';
    $scope.target = 'TargetTwo';
    $scope.trackedTargetHit = false;
});

<div ng-controller="CtrlOne" >
    <section ng-class="{'white' : trackedTargetHit}" track-position target="target">
    </section>
</div>

<div ng-controller="CtrlTwo" >
    <section ng-class="{'white' : trackedTargetHit}" track-position target="target">
    </section>
</div>
```

this works fine with just one directive, but used twice it musses up. i know this has something to do with my misuse of scopes in the directive. but getting very confused about how to use correctly; any suggestions greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
 window.onscroll = function() {
```

which is a global event handler.  It is getting overwritten by subsequent directive calls - you will only ever have one handler when you do it this way.  If you are including jQuery (and maybe even if not, I don't know if jqLite handles this) you can change it to

```
 $(window).on('scroll', function() {
```

and it will automatically take care of the event having two event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to dave this is working now:

```
/* track position */
app.directive("trackPosition", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            var elemTop = elem[0].offsetTop;
                targetTop = document.getElementById(scope.target).getBoundingClientRect().top;

            (targetTop <= elemTop && (-1 * targetTop) <= elemTop) ? scope.trackedTargetHit = true : scope.trackedTargetHit = false;
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```